# How to get SharePoint buttons on the same line using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I don't have any experience using HTML code, but I wanted to display buttons on a SharePoint page on the same line. It currently just lets me arrange the buttons on top of each other. This takes too much real estate on the page and creates unnecessary white space. I do not want to create separate sections on the page for individual buttons.

The buttons house a link to views in a document library.

Is there a way I can do that using The Modern Script Web Part?

The button names:

- Presentation documents.
- Report documents.
- All other documents.

We are using SharePoint Online with no Power Apps.

Thank you

Comment: You can also create a section with 3 columns which will have 3 button control next to each other OR use other web parts like quick links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achive what you want using the "[Quick Links](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82)" web part. It looks like a list of buttons.

You can, of course, build it using the script web part (or even your own web part), but that would need admin permissions to install and enable this web part (thus compromising security), and then some efforts writing html code and then supporting all that mess.